# Fallo SSH en phpstom con GIT ( Bitbucket )

Tags: git, bitbucket, phpstorm

Me gustaría saber si alguien me puede ayudar, uso Phpstorm como editor principal y hace poco me he unido a un equipo de trabajo por lo que queremos trabajar con GIT . La verdad es que llevaba bastante sin usarlo cuando lo hacía, usaba GIT y tortoise. Ahora quiero usarlo desde phpstorm pero sale el siguiente fallo:

> @bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey). Could not read from remote repository.  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

He generado la ppk con PuTTy y guardado en la carpeta **C:/users//.ssh/clave.ppk** pero por alguna razón phpstorm no lo detecta, y eso que en su última versión trabaja con la clave de forma nativa. Decir que directamente con GIT desde la ubicación del proyecto sí que puedo hacerlo todo.

¿Alguien me puede orientar?

Gracias

Comment: No digo que no se pueda hacer así como lo haces, pero siempre que generado claves se me ha generado un fichero `id_rsa` con la clave privada y un fichero `id_rsa.pub` con la clave pública en el directorio `.ssh`. Tampoco he necesitado usar Putty para esto. Generalmente utilizo lo que viene aqui: https://docs.github.com/es/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent Lógicamente también hay que añadirlas en bitbucket para registrarlas, supongo que esto no se os habrá olvidado.

Comment: Nono, esta añadida, el tema es que veo todo lo que pasa en bitbucket desde phpstorm, es algo muy curioso.

Comment: @ordago He generado las claves directamente en GIT y PUM!, phpstorm funciona perfectamente. Gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Fallo aclarado, el problema era que **las llaves generadas con PuTTy** no estaban haciendo su labor. He hecho como el compañero @ordago me ha dicho, es decir, **generar las llaves directamente con GIT Bash** y perfecto, todo funcionando.

Gracias :)